# Refreshing page on database modification

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the main page of my website there is a long list, `<ul>`. Each list item represents a model object. Within the list there are the objects attributes, for example its name etc, and also buttons to change those attributes. The list is loaded from the sqlite database. The issue is since each button changes data in the database, to display the changed data, the view function reloads the page on each button click. That is fine, except the list is very long, and is necessary to scroll down, and on each button click, the page is reloaded therefore goes to the very top of the list. This makes the webpage almost unusable, or at least very annoying to use.

Can someone recommend a workaround to this problem. Please let me know if my question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to achieve is something that should be done with Javascript. It will be the simplest way of doing it! For instance, you can call the corresponding API when the user clicks on one of the buttons, and if the API returns 'OK' then you can just update the item with the changes you made (because if the server returned yes, then you can assume that the local version of the data is the same than the one on the server)

Comment: Thanks. Currently button click actions are done in the backend, in the view function. You are suggesting creating an API using django rest framework, and using javascript to call that api on button clicks, and modify the html from javascript?

Comment: Yes except that you can directly create your API with JsonResponse, you are not obliged to go through the process of installing the rest framework (which would probably be pointless if you don't need an auth system)

Comment: Thanks. I will accept the answer after doing some more research, though this seems to be what I'm looking for.